# HQL Query most recent timestamp in Many to Many relationship

Tags: sql, database, hibernate, jpa, hql

### DB

```
     A         B                A_B
   -----     -----             ------
    id         id               A_id
    name       time_stamp       B_id
               desc
```

### Models

```
     A         B                
   -----     -----           
    id         id             
    name       time_stamp
    [B]        desc
```

I am trying to make an HQL query that will pull all of A where B's time_stamp is the most recent and only pull that row back if the desc is 'Done'. Here is what I currently have:

```
select a from A a
        inner join a.B b
        where b.time_stamp in (
        select max(selectedB.time_stamp) from B selectedB
        where selectedB.id = b.id)
        and b.desc = 'Done'
```

This does not seem to work. It seems to only respect the desc and not care about the time select. Any ideas?